# If I use a proxy on my gaming console, can someone find my real IP or boot me from a game?

Tags: attacks, vpn, proxy, gaming

Will a proxy work like a VPN or not? What site has working proxy?

Comment: Console, I meant PS3 and PS4. Can someone get my real ip using proxy online in game?. I have problem with setting up vpn on my pc to ps3,ps4 and doesn't work. I wanted to know if proxy will hide my IP.

Comment: Who are you concerned about?  Governments? Law enforcement? Companies? Or random gamers online?  The answer changes depending on who is going after you.  As far as boot you, that is generally by your id, not your ip.  Proxies can change ips, but the id is on you.

Comment: When I Google "PS3 proxy" I get a LOT of rich results (including sites offering proxies). I think your answer is there.

Comment: When your plan is to work around bans, then changing or concealing your IP address is not going to work in many games. Games identify you by your device ID or your account name on the game console's online service.

Answer (score 4):

A proxy is designed to act on your behalf, so in theory, it should hide your IP, but it depends on a lot of factors including what traffic flows through the proxy.

This should address your worries about being "booted".

Proxies and VPNs perform very different functions, and I leave that research to you. In terms of hiding your IP, they can basically hide your IP equally well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, PS3 and PS4 only allow use of HTTP proxies, so your actual game connection (which is probably using UDP) isn't going to use it, so your real IP will be exposed to everyone in your lobby/game.

To protect your IP, you'll need to use VPN on your computer and route your console through it. From my experience playing through VPN isn't really practical as it's going to increase your ping.

Answer (score -2):

I were to be completely technical ...No your IP is there somewhere and can be traced back. However, in practice that would require immense amount of time/resources so don't worry.